# How to read text from Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox in different thread - Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8.1

How to read text from Text from `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox` in different thread in Windows Phone 8.1?

Following line of throws exception while accessing text from `txtUserName`.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtUserName.Text.IsNull() || txtPassword.Text.IsNull()) return;

    var task = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(DoLoginAsync);

    task.Start();
}

private async void  DoLoginAsync()
{
    string userName = txtUserName.Text;
    string password = txtPassword.Text;

    var apiReq = new WebAPIRequest();
    var response = await apiReq.APIRequest<Request, Response>(Action.LogIn, new Request { UserName = userName, Password = password });
    // Code..
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why creating and starting a new thread? There is no need for it, just add "async" to btnLogin_Click and await your DoLoginAsync method.